# C#: accessing the next or previous element by button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have a project that use the button to access to the next or previous element in a generic collection
the student class has 3 properties: string lastname, firstname and city.
can anyone help me to enable that?
I think it may relate to IEnumerator(), but I get stuck

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        txtFirstName.Clear();
        txtLastName.Clear();
        txtCity.Clear();
    }

    private void btnCreateStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Student stu = new Student();
        stu.Firstname = txtFirstName.Text;
        stu.Lastname = txtLastName.Text;
        stu.City = txtCity.Text;
        //List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
        Students.Add(stu);
        //string s = Convert.ToString(Students.Count);
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
        txtFirstName.Clear();
        txtLastName.Clear();
        txtCity.Clear();

    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I need to access to the next element by press this button, the current is the member that i has just created 




    }
   }
```

Comment: Are you stuck with 3 property or not ?

Comment: no, i think 3 properties are Ok, just wonder how to access to the element in the List<>?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to maintain some type of state of where you currently are in the list of `Student` objects.  Then each time you click the next button it returns the next object and increments like this:

```
private int counter;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtFirstName.Clear();
    txtLastName.Clear();
    txtCity.Clear();

    counter = 0;
}

....

private Student getNextStudent()
{
    Student s = Students[counter % (Students.Length - 1)];
    //the modulo operator simply prevents the counter from an IndexOutOfBounds exception 
    //and instead just loops back to the first Student.

    counter++;
    return s;
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Student s = getNextStudent();
     //insert the properties of s into the text fields or whatever you want to do
}
```

If you make any changes to the student list at any point this example will stop working properly.  You shouldn't modify the `Students` collection as it can mess up the iteration.  You'd need to add in additional code to handle that situation.